# Showing that sequence converges to accumulation point (follow up)

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that sequence converges to accumulation point
>
> **Sol** : If $\{a_{n}\}$ has an accumulation point, say, $a$, and $(a_{n})$ is convergent. Then choose some $n_{1}$ such that $a_{n_{1}}\in B_{1}(a)-\{a\}$. Then choose some $n_{2}$ such that $B_{1/2}(a)-\{a,a_{1},...,a_{n_{1}}\}$, proceed in this way we have $a_{n_{k}}\rightarrow a$. Since $(a_{n})$ is convergent, one has $a_{n}\rightarrow a$.
>
> [From](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2550128/convergent-sequences-and-accumulation-points)

I don't understand the answer from the "choose some $n_2$ such that $B_{\frac12} (a) - \{ a, a_1...,a_{n_1} \}$". What does $n_2$ have to do with the ball with points of sequence removed..?

And, how does proceeding in this way mean that $a_{n_k} \to a$ happens..?

Answer (score 1):

I think its supposed to be $a_{n_2} \in B_{1/2}(a) - \{a_1, \ldots, a_{n_1}\}$. Then in general $a_{n_{k+1}} \in B_{(1/2^{k})}(a) - \{a_1,\ldots, a_{n_{k}}\}$

Answer (score 1):

$a$ is an accumulation point of $A=\{x_n\}$ implies any open set $U$  containing $a$ intersect $A\setminus\{a\}$.

$\forall k\in \Bbb{N}$ choose a sequence $(x_{n_k})\in  B(a, \frac{1}{k}) \cap A\setminus \{a\}$

$|x_{n_k}-a|<\frac{1}{k}\to \infty \text{  as } n\to \infty$

Then $(x_{n_k}) $ converges to $a$ and since $(x_{n_k})$ is a subsequence of the convergent sequence $(x_n) $ , hence $(x_n) \to a$.

Comment: Hmm valid points but I can't seem to relate your answer into the doubts I asked. Could you please quote text and write the part of answer underneath which answers my q''

Comment: Ping just incase you didn't see the message